# Cannot show the images of a particular user

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I m working in asp.net and I want to show picture of a user whose Profile_ID is 1. I am directly saving pictures into database in varbinary format. and retrieving it in gridview. The problem I am facing is that when a user logs in and clicks on "See photos"  button, the same picture comes four times if a user has uploaded 4 different pictures. It is not taking all of the four pictures which a user has uploaded. I am doing it using handler.

This is my table specification:
Table name : (Photo)
Columns: Photo_ID, Profile_ID(Foreign Key), Photo

Below is my GridView code

```
     <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# "ThumbNail.ashx?proid="+ Eval("Profile_ID") %>' Height="200px" Width="200px"/>
```

this is how I am binding data to grid

```
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(strCon);
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT Photo_ID,Profile_ID from [Photo] where Profile_ID=" +Session["profileid"], connection);
        SqlDataAdapter daimages = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        daimages.Fill(dt);
        gridview.DataSource = dt;
        gridview.DataBind();
```

and this the coding of handler where I am doing main work of retrieving images

```
       string pid = context.Request.QueryString["proid"];
       string query = "select Photo from Photo where  Profile_ID=" + pid;
       SqlDataAdapter adpt = new SqlDataAdapter(query, connection);
       DataTable dt = new DataTable();
       adpt.Fill(dt);
       for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
    {

        context.Response.BinaryWrite((byte[])(dt.Rows[i]["Photo"]));
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the table has both `Photo_ID` and `Profile_ID`, but you are using `Profile_ID` in the handler.

I would use `Photo_ID` as the parameter in the handler,

```
<%# "ThumbNail.ashx?photoid="+ Eval("Photo_ID") %>' Height="200px" Width="200px"/>
```

and update the handler to this.

```
   string pid = context.Request.QueryString["photoid"];
   string query = "select Photo from Photo where  Photo_ID=" + pid;
```

Comment: By using this how only those pictures will be fetched which are uploaded by that particular user? Because I want pictures according to Profile_ID (which are uploaded by that particular Profile_ID)

Comment: You are already taking care of that with the databinding of the grid. `SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT Photo_ID,Profile_ID from [Photo] where Profile_ID=" +Session["profileid"], connection);`

Comment: Great!  Please mark this as the answer so others can search for it.

Comment: I accepted your answer but can't vote it because it requires much reputation :D